# Is there any way to communicate between API and Worker service via http request (and vice versa)?

Tags: c#, .net-core

The idea is to have a worker service doing heavy tasks when requested from an API.

Example of communication:

**API:** Post data to worker service

**Worker service:** Post data back when its done.

I've done some research but can't find any solution to what I'm looking for.

Is it possible? If not, there is any other way to do it?

Comment: Check this out: https://itnext.io/background-workers-in-net-core-api-f6fac7a5477f

Answer (score 0):

afaik there is no built-in mechanism to do this so you could use a database or queue to request the work to be carried out and then the worker can poll this db/queue to handle the workload.

Answer (score 0):

I use RabbitMQ to communicate between threads in Python on Linux as well as using it for asp.net to communicate with window services (of course running on another thread). The service/worker checks the message queue every iteration/loop and performs work based on what's in the message. The message of course gets pushed into the queue by aspnet, usually through functionality in a controller.

A quick google will get you good results on RabbitMQ and aspnet. Not only can you use this with a worker, but other programs/services you have running on the system.

First link from google that might help you along the way.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/rabbitmq-message-queue-using-net-core-6-web-api/

I have implemented this into my own project. I have a Service on the aspnet side, where a controller calls it topost messages onto the queue. The Worker checks the queue on every loop and performs functions.

Here is the worker service

```
 public class SchedulerWorkerService : BackgroundService
{
    string queueName = "SchedulerQueue";
    private readonly IConnectionFactory factory;
    private readonly IConnection connection;
    private readonly IModel channel;
    public SchedulerWorkerService()
    {
        factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };
        connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        channel = connection.CreateModel();
        channel.QueueDeclare(queueName, exclusive: false); 
    }


    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            BasicGetResult result = channel.BasicGet(queueName, true);
            if (result != null && result.Body.Length > 0)
            {
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.Body.ToArray());

                // Do you work based on the message here.
                switch (message)
                {
                    case "PAUSE SERVICE":
                        // Stop scheduled task processing
                        break;
                    case "REFRESH":
                        // Perfrom logic to refresh all data stored in variables from database
                        break;
                    case "SHUTDOWN":
                        // perform any shutdown logic to processes
                        break;
                }
            } 
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        channel.Close();
        channel.Dispose();
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Here is the service that pushes messages onto the queue

```
    public class SchedulerWorkerCommService
{

    public void StopService()
    {

    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };
        var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        using var channel = connection.CreateModel();
        channel.QueueDeclare("SchedulerQueue", exclusive: false); 
        channel.BasicPublish("", "SchedulerQueue", body: Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
    }
}
```